# Reading file using Javascript ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"), the data from file is strange

Tags: javascript

I use this code for get contents from local:

```
function readFile(filePath)
{
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var forReading = 1;
    var file = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, forReading,false, 0);
    var text = file.ReadAll();
    file.close();
    console.log(text);

    return text;
}
```

Input file's contents is:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

but console.log(text) prints:

```
癤풹aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What encoding is the file?

Comment: encoding of the file is utf-8